# c# WPF Datagrid image

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a local sql db with a table "Clubs" this table contains fields namely "id", "ClubName" (string) and "ClubLogo" (string) .
The "ClubLogo" is a path, these are located in "appl.UI/Images" and are of type png.
Question: How can I visualize this image in my datagrid?

Answer (score 0):

You could define a `DataGridTemplateColumn` with a `CellTemplate` that displays an `Image` bound to the path:

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding ClubLogo}" Stretch="None" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks, but Don't work for my !!

Comment: What doesn't work? What is the path?

Comment: The `appl.UI/Images` path prefix mentioned in the question is certainly missing.

Comment: `ClubLogo` should obviously include a valid path.